# Can't enqueue new scripts into parents theme

Tags: css, wordpress, lightbox2

I'm trying to add new scripts and a css file to my child's theme on wordpress but i'm getting the following errors.

```
GET https://linton59.co.uk/wp-content/themes/simpleshift/css/lightbox.css?ver=4.3.0 net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):280 GET https://linton59.co.uk/wp-content/themes/simpleshift/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js?ver=3.3.0 net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):279 GET https://linton59.co.uk/wp-content/themes/simpleshift/js/lightbox.js?ver=3.3.0 net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):68 GET https://linton59.co.uk/wp-content/themes/simpleshift/css/lightbox.css?ver=4.3.0 net::ERR_ABORTED
```

The following is the functions.php i'm using.

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'bootstrap','font-awesome' ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts', 20 );
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'simpleshift_public' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/public.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_light', 30 );
function theme_light() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'simpleshift_public' );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'lightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/lightbox.css', array(), '4.3.0' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.3.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.3.0', true );




}
```

My child's theme has a css folder and js folder with the relevant files in it.
The last action is the only part not working.

Comment: get_template_directory_uri() will always return the URI of the current parent theme.

To get the child theme URI instead, you need to use get_stylesheet_directory_uri().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_template_directory_uri() will always return the URI of the current parent theme.

To get the child theme URI instead, you need to use get_stylesheet_directory_uri().